# ContactFilter2d Layermask - For Ground Check

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

Little detail:

Hey guys! I don't have my computer infront of me as im at work. I'm actually watching videos on stuff to do when I get home so I will pull code the best I can.

When it comes to creating a jump on a platform character, in most cases what I have seen is an object attached to the bottom of the character, and then a ground check is created to see if that object is hitting something.

### The tutorial I was following has way to many different components to check for. ( https://youtu.be/05TCTrpGB-4?t=6m54s )| exact moment for code.

Actual issue:

So I've been trying to come up with my own way that seemed more simple, but I am stuck. So I figure, I want to say that if the collider on this player touches ANY other collider, for Grounded to be true.

```
    //Variable:
private bool Grounded;

//movement handle
void HandleMovement(){
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)){
    Ninjabody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpspeed ForcemMode.Impulse);
}
}
```

Then I followed the reference guides: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html

So, to apply this, it says to use `public bool IsTouching(Collider2D collider);`

I couldnt figure out if the Collider is the name of the collider it is hitting, if so I named it platform and placed it. Once I tested it I got an error.

I tried to google the error for you guys, but it essentially says that Ninja1.IsTouching needs to have a body because it is not marked as something.

From my understanding it means that IsTouching needed to be called. I could not get this to work, so instead i switched to Laymasks trying to use ContactFilter ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactFilter2D-layerMask.html )

```
private LasyerMask Platforms;
```

Then tried to call it in its own function, but I dont know how to set this up. The reference guide ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html ) Only provides information regarding it as a variable:

```
public bool IsTouching(Collider2D platform, ContactFilter2D Platforms);
```

If I create a method and call the method inside of handlemovement it breaks even more. I've tried looking it up, but I could not find references to using IsTouching, and the references in unity send me in circles to creating a variable, but I have no idea how to apply that variable.

I would be forever grateful for an understanding to why this isn't working, and what I am missing to have this go through. I know this post is a little verbose, but It's better i add more detail than not enough leaving with assistance having questions. Thank you all in advance as per usual.

Comment: To add a little more: The tutorial uses a totally diff system. There is an array of game objects that are at the feet of the character [3] and he then calls to check all 3 of these components with physics2d, and a for each loop. It technically works, but it's really long and i wanted a simpler code to control. Thank you all for reading.

Comment: Why are you making something this easy really complicated? There are many examples of `IsTouching` out there.  You don't need to doc to find one. Just google it. `player.collider.IsTouching(ground.collider)`..... The other duplicate link shows another way to do this without the `IsTouching` function